# How to query a BigQuery table from DataLab notebook using google.datalab.bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-platform

I have the following code in DataLab notebook:

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq

%bq query
SELECT count(id) FROM 'rtda.tweets'
```

It returns the error:

```
invalidQuery: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'rtda.tweets' at [1:23]
```

The BiqQuery table schema is correctly returned the by bigquery schema command:

```
%bigquery schema --table "rtda.tweets"

name        type        mode        description
created_at  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
id          INTEGER     NULLABLE    
id_str      STRING      NULLABLE    
(...)
```

In BigQuery console I am able to successfully execute the query:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM [rtda.tweets];
```

The problem is that I am not able to execute this command in DataLab notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query shown above is defined using legacy SQL however standard SQL is the preferred SQL dialect for querying data stored in BigQuery according to the BigQuery [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql). According to the [datalab to google.datalab Migration Guide](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/%60datalab%60-to-%60google.datalab%60-Migration-Guide), Legacy SQL is no longer supported in `google.datalab`. Can you convert your queries to Standard SQL?

For Standard SQL, change the quotes `'` around the table name to backticks

```
%bq query

SELECT count(id) FROM `rtda.tweets`
```

The reason this works in the BigQuery console is that the console still supports legacy SQL whereas `google.datalab` does not.

Comment: Since this table name doesn't use any special characters - you can drop backticks and use just SELECT count(id) FROM rtda.tweets